# Conditional on declaration of static list

Tags: c#

For example I have a static List of a class:

```
    public static List<MadjType> MAASource = new List<MadjType>
    {
        new MadjType{Id = 1, Name = "MAA - 1"},
        new MadjType{Id = 2, Name = "MAA - 2"},
        new MadjType{Id =3, Name = "MAA - 3"},
        new MadjType{Id = 4, Name = "MAA - 4"},
        new MadjType{Id = 5, Name = "MAA - 5"},
        new MadjType{Id = 6, Name = "MAA - 6"},
        new MadjType{Id = 7, Name = "MAA - 7"},
        new MadjType{Id = 8, Name = "MAA - 8"},
        new MadjType{Id = 9, Name="MAA - 9"},
        new MadjType{Id = 10, Name= "MAA - 10"},
    };
```

And I have a resource file that tells me whether I am building for Version1 or Version2 (I use this as a conditional for other parts of the solution, such as

```
if (ConfigurationResource.Version == "Version2")
{
//return different values
}
```

).

So, for Version2, I don't want to add the last few items on this static list, so meaning:

```
    new MadjType{Id = 8, Name = "MAA - 8"},
    new MadjType{Id = 9, Name="MAA - 9"},
    new MadjType{Id = 10, Name= "MAA - 10"},
```

should not be included in MAASource when I am using Version2 as declared on the resource file.

Is there any way I can do this for this static List?

Comment: can't you have MAASource contain only the common elements, and then based on condition for version 1, version 2 add the respective elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends if you can access `ConfigurationResource.Version` statically. If so, you can use a static constructor to initialize `MAASource`.

```
public static List<MadjType> MAASource { get; set; }

static MyClass(){
    if (ConfigurationResource.Version == "Version1")
    {
        //return values for Version1
    }
    if (ConfigurationResource.Version == "Version2")
    {
        //return values for Version2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize the values in a static constructor. But that would require that the Version is available within the static context as well.

```
public static List<MadjType> MAASource { get; private set; }

static MyClass()
{
    switch (ConfigurationResource.Version)
    {
        case "Version1":
            MAASource = new List<MadjType>
                {
                    new MadjType { Id = 1, Name = "MAA - 1" },
                    new MadjType { Id = 2, Name = "MAA - 2" },
                    new MadjType { Id = 3, Name = "MAA - 3" },
                    new MadjType { Id = 4, Name = "MAA - 4" },
                    new MadjType { Id = 5, Name = "MAA - 5" },
                    new MadjType { Id = 6, Name = "MAA - 6" },
                    new MadjType { Id = 7, Name = "MAA - 7" },
                    new MadjType { Id = 8, Name = "MAA - 8" },
                    new MadjType { Id = 9, Name = "MAA - 9" },
                    new MadjType { Id = 10, Name = "MAA - 10" },
                };
            break;

        case "Version2":
            MAASource = new List<MadjType>
                {
                    new MadjType { Id = 1, Name = "MAA - 1" },
                    new MadjType { Id = 2, Name = "MAA - 2" },
                    new MadjType { Id = 3, Name = "MAA - 3" },
                    new MadjType { Id = 4, Name = "MAA - 4" },
                    new MadjType { Id = 5, Name = "MAA - 5" },
                    new MadjType { Id = 6, Name = "MAA - 6" },
                    new MadjType { Id = 7, Name = "MAA - 7" },
                };
            break;
    }
}
```

And you could just create the list and add items depending on the version rather than defining the entire set within the case statements.